# Bool not working when I rapidly press assigned button

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to create flappy bird like game. and this is the scripts.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float jumpForce;
    public float jumpForward;
    public float goinBack;
    public float chargingStart;
    public float maxCharge = 1f;
    public float moveForce;

    private Vector2 reSpawn;

    public bool isGrounded;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        reSpawn = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        OnClick();

        if(rb.position.x < -10f)
        {
            transform.position = reSpawn;
        }

        transform.position = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -11f, 11f), rb.position.y);

    }

    private void OnClick()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            chargingStart += Time.deltaTime + Time.deltaTime;
            
            if (chargingStart >= 1f)
            {
                chargingStart = maxCharge;
            }

        }
        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1") && isGrounded == true)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(jumpForward * chargingStart, jumpForce * chargingStart);
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() 
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(goinBack, rb.velocity.y);
        }        
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) 
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            isGrounded = true;
            chargingStart = 0f;
        }
        if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Obstacle"))
        {
            isGrounded = true;
            chargingStart = 0f;
        }
        
    }
}
```

this is the best I can do since I just start learning about Unity and C#. the scripts, the game works like I want it to be. The problem is when I rapidly press the assigned button, *isGrounded* became *false* even if player is in collision with the ground. please help! thanks in advance.

Comment: Can it be that your player never leaves the ground/ continues to touch the same collider?

Comment: There's no problem if I play it slowly. but if rapid press it for 3 times/ 4 times, the problem occurs. like taptaptap. but if I like tap . . . tap . . . tap . . ., no problem.

Comment: Which are usually called race conditions. You are doing your ground check in an once off event (OnCollisionEnter2D), you could just do the same check in OnCollisionStay2D for isGrounded (charging reset in the OnCollisionStay2D would probably be not a good idea) and see if that fixes the issue. If it does, you might want to rethink how you detect isGrounded